# Cannot catch scroll-event in vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have this.

```
<template>
    <md-dialog :md-active.sync="show"
               @md-closed="hideModal"
               @md-clicked-outside="hideModal"
               class="modal-tabs"
               @keypress.enter.prevent="handleEnter"
    >
        <md-dialog-content ref="my-modal" v-on:scroll.native="handleScrolling" @click.native="handleScrolling">
            <!--content-->
        </md-dialog-content>
    </md-dialog>
</template>
```

and handler function is

```
handleScrolling(): void {
    console.log('scroll is on');
    this.$root.$emit('scrollingModal', this.$refs['my-modal'].$el.scrollTop);
}
```

It easily called by clicking on content but cannot be called by scrolling content. Why? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `v-on:scroll` to be triggered the element first needs to by overflowing with a scroll style declared.

Try doing this:

```html
<div style="max-height: 300px; overflow: scroll;" v-on:scroll="handleScrolling()">
    <md-dialog-content ref="my-modal" @click.native="handleScrolling">
            <!--content-->
    </md-dialog-content>
</div>
```

This should show you a proof of concept. As you scroll inside that `div` you should see the messages being logged.

Comment: As far as i know <md-dialog-content> is provide scroll possibility for wrapped content including relevant css styles (overflow).

Comment: ```.md-dialog-content {
    padding: 0 24px 24px;
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}``` this appears in dev tool for code above

Comment: I have tried this solution, but, unfortunately, it does not helped, also, with this,  click-event stopped to firing.

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved by wrapping **content** with *md-tabs* and *md-tab* tags. In my case, to achieve scroll event triggering i have changed code above to:

```
<template>
    <md-dialog :md-active.sync="show"
               @md-closed="hideModal"
               @md-clicked-outside="hideModal"
               class="modal-tabs"
               @keypress.enter.prevent="handleEnter"
    >
        <md-dialog-content ref="edit-contact-modal" v-on:scroll.native="handleScrolling">
            <md-tabs>
                <md-tab><!--here md-tab in fact is first custom div of mine-->
                    <!--content-->
                </md-tab>
            </md-tabs>
        </md-dialog-content>
    </md-dialog>
</template>
```